# Cannot connect bluetooth W-Touch touchpad to ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, touchpad, connection

I just bought a nice touchpad, working on Windows 10 but I'm not able to run it on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it. Product link : https://www.brydge.eu/products/w-touch

My bluetooth settings don't see it but in command line, with bluez, GATT or with this scan command I see it :

```
hcitool lescan
```

When I found the MAC adress I tried this command line with GATT tool :

```
gatttool -b <mac_adress> --addr-type=random --primary
```

I got this answer :

```
connect: Connection refused (111)
```

I try with bluetoothctl but the scan don't see the device.

I don't know what to do, I search on many forums which has similar problems with low-energy bluetooth but no one works in my case.

Some forums says to change the /etc/bluetooth/bluetooth.conf file but I just have these files in this folder : input.conf, main.conf and network.conf. And no lines matches with what they said. (Sorry I don't find anymore the forum ^^)

Any further idea ?

Comment: +1  Same problem here. I wonder if anyone at all here cares about Bluetooth not working ?

Comment: When you talk about steps you tried from another site/forum, link to them. StackExchange is for the benefit of everyone, not just the Original Poster.